# Issue with my Left outer join query

Tags: sql, left-join

Here are my tables,

[image]

I'm trying to fetch the list of free bets with the details if the user has placed his bet or not. This is the query i have written to fetch the details for the same,

```
select DISTINCT tbl_CreateFreeBet.FreeBetID, 
        tbl_CreateFreeBet.FreeBetDescription, 
        tbl_CreateFreeBet.FreeBetAmount, 
        tbl_CreateFreeBet.TournamentID, 
        tbl_CreateFreeBet.MatchID, 
        tbl_UserFreeBets.UserForYes, 
        tbl_UserFreeBets.UserForNo, 
        tbl_UserFreeBets.UserForNoBets  
from tbl_CreateFreeBet left outer join tbl_UserFreeBets
on tbl_CreateFreeBet.MatchID = 1 and
tbl_CreateFreeBet.MatchID = tbl_UserFreeBets.MatchID and 
tbl_CreateFreeBet.FreeBetID = tbl_UserFreeBets.FreeBetID and 
tbl_CreateFreeBet.TournamentID = tbl_UserFreeBets.TournamentID and 
(tbl_UserFreeBets.UserForYes = 'User2' or tbl_UserFreeBets.UserForNo = 
'User2')
```

This is working fine, when there is a data in tbl_CreateFreeBet table for the MatchID. But if there is no data, then this query is not returning the expected result.

For example: With tbl_CreateFreeBet.MatchID = 1, I need to get all the free bets of matchID = 1, with the details of the passed in user, if has bet on 'yes' or 'no'. This comes up fine, as there is data for MatchId = 1 in tbl_CreateFreeBet.

But, it fails, when the tbl_CreateFreeBet.MatchID = 2 input is passed. Here there is no free bet created for the MatchID = 2. But still it returns me the result for MatchID=1.

Please share the query if one is aware of what changes need to be done for my query. Thank you.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function (on a column), it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows! Remove those redundant parentheses to make things clearer, i.e. do `select DISTINCT tbl_CreateFreeBet.FreeBetID, ...`

Comment: @jarlh Updated as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions on the *first* table in a `LEFT JOIN` should be in the `WHERE` clause.  I think you intend this logic:

```
select cfb.FreeBetID, cfb.FreeBetDescription, cfb.FreeBetAmount, 
       cfb.TournamentID, cfb.MatchID, 
       ufb.UserForYes, ufb.UserForNo, ufb.UserForNoBets  
from tbl_CreateFreeBet cfb left outer join
     tbl_UserFreeBets ufb
     on cfb.MatchID = ufb.MatchID and 
        cfb.FreeBetID = ufb.FreeBetID and 
        cfb.TournamentID = ufb.TournamentID and 
        (ufb.UserForYes = 'User2' or ufb.UserForNo = 'User2')
where cfb.MatchId = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Worked perfect.